Realtime Notification Service Cloud Service
When developing a real-time notification service for users, as a .NET developer, I am exploring various technologies and cloud services to implement this feature. In terms of technology standards, options include Web Sockets, MQTT, and Pub/Sub, with frameworks like SignalR and Socket.IO supporting real-time communication.
In the cloud space, multiple cloud providers offer services for real-time communication, such as AWS (AWS IoT Core, Amazon SNS), Azure (Azure SignalR, Azure Web Pub/Sub, Azure IoT Hub), and Google Cloud (Google Pub/Sub).
For my specific use case, where User A needs to publish notifications to all users subscribed to a group, with a user base of 100k and the requirement to maintain connections for all users, I am seeking guidance on selecting the most suitable cloud service.
The key challenge is efficiently distributing notifications to 100k users and managing the associated connections. I am looking for recommendations on which cloud service would be best suited for this scenario, considering factors like scalability, reliability, performance, and cost.
Any insights or advice on choosing the appropriate cloud service for implementing a real-time notification system with a large user base and high connection requirements would be greatly appreciated.
